# Setting background color of new rows in Bootstrap Table

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-table

I am using `Bootstrap Table` with the `Editable` plugin. I have a button to add new rows to the table. I like to have the cell for the new row in the `Notes` column have a background color of blue.

From the [documentation](http://bootstrap-table.wenzhixin.net.cn/documentation/):

```
function cellStyle(value, row, index, field) {
  return {
    classes: 'text-nowrap another-class',
    css: {"color": "blue", "font-size": "50px"}
  };
}
```

The only thing that is consistent with those parameters and adding a new row is the index = 0, so I default all the others to `Null`. It seems like my function is not even being called. I'm new to `JavaSript` so I might just be missing something.

http://jsfiddle.net/8gk0ogtp/1/

```
 $button = $('#button');
    $(function () {
        $button.click(function () {
            $table.bootstrapTable('insertRow', {
                index: 0,
                row: {}
            });
            cellStyle();
        });
    });

function cellStyle1(value=Null, row=Null, index=0, field=Null) {  
   return {css: {"background-color": "blue"}}
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this one

http://jsfiddle.net/bitriddler/qjht8stb/

**Changes:**

When adding new rows I added `paintBlue=true`

Updated `cellStyle` to this

```
function cellStyle(value=Null, row=Null, index=0, field=Null) {
    if(row.paintBlue) {
        return {css: {"background-color": "blue"}}
    }
    return {};
}
```

Passing `cellStyle` function when defining columns instead of passing in html `data-cell-style` attribute

```
...
{
    field: 'Notes',
    sortable: 'true',
    cellStyle: cellStyle,
    title: 'Notes',
    editable: {
    type: 'textarea'
}
...
```